# responsive css layout picture

Tags: html, css, responsive

[Image 1 (What I get)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGJdO.jpg)

[Image 2 (What I want)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAUMX.jpg)

I want to implement responsive layout like the second picture. But what I got is the first picture.

My CSS code is:

```
    @media (max-width: 960px){
.nav{
    width: 100%;
    height:2em;}

#nav-icon{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3%;
}
.container div{
    display: inline;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1%;

}
.container div img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Could anyone help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Can we see your html?

Comment: Please post all your code as JSFiddle.
also read this page, It's good http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create a responsive layout using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)'s [grid layout](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Procedure How you create: 
create a grid using `col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6`
in the first col create a `img` with full height. and in the second column create two `img` src which will placed as in vertical way using `CSS` property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using Bootstrap grid system we can easily make responsive images.

here is the code for your picture. if there is any alignment missing according to screen width. fix that by using the @media rule.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="display:absolute;">
       <div class="col-xs-6">
           <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/neOKPvD.png">
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-6">
           <div class="col-xs-12">
           <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/fYeBJ8S.png">
            <h4>Add text here</h4>
            <p>description</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-12">
           <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/Y6wIPnl.png">
           </div>
       </div>
    </div> 
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<body>

<h1>Run In Full Page </h1>

<div class="w3-row w3-col s9 ">

<div class="w3-container w3-half ">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OKzIMYS.png">
</div>

<div class="w3-container w3-rest ">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/HcNSP13.png">  
<p class="w3-large" <strong> Animated Vector</strong> </p>
<p class="w3-text-grey w3-opacity w3-large"><i>Art, Design, Web </i></p>
<br>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/DiqFrE1.png">
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all~~~
I think I figure out how to do that. I use css3's property: column.([css3 column property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp))I think it it quite same as the bootstrap grid layout.
It's my first time to post question here, and I got so many answers in such a short time. You guys are awesome!
Thanks again!